# How to center my navigation bar between two uneven elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I've been messing with my code for about two days now and everything I do does not work. I want the nav bar to be centered between two elements (`<img>, <form>`). It is roughly centered now but when you re-size the window it messes up at around 1600px. It only needs to work up to 1500px because after that I'm going to go onto a different nav bar location and style.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpECd

HTML:

```
<header>
        <img src="../Images/Logo.svg" class="logo">   
        <nav>
            <a href="#" class="one">SHARING</a>
            <a href="#" class="two">HOSTING</a>
            <a href="#" class="three">PRICING</a>
            <a href="#" class="four">ACCOUNT</a>
        </nav>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <button value="SIGNUP" name="signup">SIGNUP</button>            
            <button value="LOGIN" name="login">LOGIN</button>
        </form>    
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

header {
    background-color:#464646;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

header .logo {
    max-height:44px;
    max-width:535px;
    margin:28px 28px 28px 28px;
}

header form {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    margin:28px 28px 28px 28px;
}

header form button {
    height:44px;
    width:125px;
    border:2px solid white;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-family:"Lato Black";
    color:white;
    font-size:22px;
}

header form button:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    cursor:pointer;
}

header form button:active {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

nav {
    width:47.5%;
    display:inline;;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}

nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:20%;
    color:white;
    font-family:"Lato Black";
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:100px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color:#00a651;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the menu and buttons to dynamically reposition themselves, or would you rather everything stay put when you resize the window and the buttons/menu just get cut off when the window is too small?  If you add a min-width to the header, you can control at which point the window switches to a scroll bar.

Comment: I have all the media queries for it to be dynamic but it just does not re-size the way I want it to. I want the navigation buttons to be "fluid" and re-size based on a percentage of the page size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 elements and you want one on the left, one on the right and the last one center between the others, you can use a table like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">
 <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="middle">
      <img src="myimage.jpg" />
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:100%;">
  <!-- width 100% will take all the spaces between the other cells -->
    <a href="#" class="one">one</a>
    <a href="#" class="two">two</a>
    <a href="#" class="three">three</a>
    <a href="#" class="four">four</a>
  </td>
  <td align="right" valign="middle">
    <form method="post" action="index.php" style="width:260px;">
        <button value="SIGNUP" name="signup" style="width:120px;">SIGNUP</button>
        <button value="LOGIN" name="login" style="width:120px;">LOGIN</button>
    </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/bk4kh0uq/)**

If you don't like tables like a lot of people, you can use div with floats and jQuery:

```
winResize = function(){

    var HeaderWidth = $("#header").outerWidth();
    var div1Width = $("#div1").outerWidth();
    var div3Width = $("#div3").outerWidth();

    var div2Width = HeaderWidth - div1Width - div3Width;
    $("#div2").css("width", div2Width+"px");
}

winResize();

$(window).resize(function(){

    winResize();
});
```

**[JQUERY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/bk4kh0uq/1/)**

Comment: From my knowledge, tables are bad and not to be used for layouts. Is there another way without a table?

Comment: @3rror404 I know it's not the proper way to do it but it is supported on almost every browser and it's the only way that I found how to do it. What would be a reason for me to use an alternate method?

Comment: Tables has a nice support for old browser, but if you want a another solution, you can do it easily with jQuery. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery solution.